# HTML inputs are not updating on handleChange

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

When I type on the inputs they don't get updated with the text that I'm typing. If I use "this.state.value" on all forms, they update all at the same time with the same text.

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

export default class ContactArea extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            name: '',
            email: '',
            tel: '',
            company: '',
            msg: ''
        };
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({value: event.target.value});

    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
        alert(this.state.value);
        event.preventDefault();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-6 form-group">
                        <label class="label-width">
                            Nome:
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" value={this.state.name} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6 form-group">
                        <label class="label-width">
                            Email:
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" value={this.state.email} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6 form-group">
                        <label class="label-width">
                            Telefone:
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" value={this.state.tel} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6 form-group">
                        <label class="label-width">
                            Empresa:
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" value={this.state.company} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-12 form-group">
                        <label class="label-width">
                            Mensagem:
                            <textarea class="form-control" type="text" value={this.state.msg} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <input type="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-primary button-width button-spacing" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        );
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now you are clearing the original state and just setting value. Try this instead

```
handleChange(event, type) {
    const newState = {};
    newState[type] = event.target.value;
    this.setState(newState);
}
```

and in the JSX for each item

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" value={this.state.name} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, 'name')} />
```

The second parameter 'name' will be passed to handleChange, which will update only the name in the current state

Alternatively you can create a function for each field **handleNameChange**, **handleEmailChange**, etc. Then only update the part of the state relevant for the field

```
handleNameChange(event) {
    this.setState({ name: event.target.value });
}

handleEmailChange(event) {
    this.setState({ email: event.target.value });
}

...
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're having trouble is because what you're doing at the moment is every time a character is entered you end up creating a new `value` property on your state object which is not what you want to do because it will always at most contain a single character, i.e. the last one that you entered and the reason your input doesn't get updated with even this single character is because you're not referring to `this.state.value` inside any of your inputs, nor should you have to because this is incorrect.

(As a note setting state like this doesn't affect your other state properties.)

So the way I would recommend you fix this is as follows:

Add a `name` attribute to each of your inputs

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" value={this.state.name} onChange={this.handleChange} />
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="email" value={this.state.email} onChange={this.handleChange} />
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="tel" value={this.state.tel} onChange={this.handleChange} />
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="company" value={this.state.company} onChange={this.handleChange} />
<textarea class="form-control" type="text" name="msg" value={this.state.msg} onChange={this.handleChange} />
```

Then modify your `handleChange` as follows:

```
handleChange(event) {
  this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
}
```

*The square brackets are an ES6's feature known as computed properties*